# What's wrong with Rows.count?

Tags: excel, vba

`Worksheets("sheet1").Range(rowCount).Rows.Count`

After I press enter the `.Count` become `.count` automatically

And I run for the code it displayed the error: **Object doesn't support this property or method**

What is the problem?

Comment: You have declared a variable somewhere? `Dim count as ...`?

Comment: Or you have declared a procudure/function/worksheet etc with that name?

Answer (score 2):

As for the error, `.Count` is a property and should be used in an expression. If you write `Worksheets("sheet1").Range(RowCount).Rows.count` separately from the expression, VBA tries to run the `.Count` method, which does not exists

```
Sub test1()
    Const count = 1 ' hence count with a small letter 
    RowCount = "A1:C10" 'for example
    ' right usage:
    x = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(RowCount).Rows.count
    ' error:
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range(RowCount).Rows.count
End Sub
```